# How can I order this union query results?

Tags: sql, union

```
(SELECT voter_category, 
count (voter_category) as responses 
FROM `bootcamp-application-project.voters_survey.survey_responses` 
where q10_1 = 1      -- Receiving long-term disability 
                    -- 1 is Yes response
group by voter_category) 
UNION ALL
( SELECT voter_category, 
count (voter_category) as responses_2
FROM `bootcamp-application-project.voters_survey.survey_responses` 
where Q10_2 = 1      -- Have a chronic illness 
group by voter_category)
Union ALL
(SELECT voter_category, 
count (voter_category) as responses_3 
FROM `bootcamp-application-project.voters_survey.survey_responses` 
where Q10_3 = 1      --  Been unemployed for more than a year
group by voter_category)
Union ALL
(SELECT voter_category, 
count (voter_category) as responses_4
FROM `bootcamp-application-project.voters_survey.survey_responses` 
where Q10_4 = 1      --  Have been evicted from your home within the past year 
group by voter_category)
```

I am using bigquery free version, I cant get the right order by to produce the results in order of the select statements in the union

Comment: It would help greatly if you provided sample data and the output you want to obtain from that data.

Comment: which sql engine?

Comment: Enclose the whole query in parentheses to make it a subquery and sort on the result with ORDER BY.

Comment: @KenWhite I am trying to return multiple columns/where clauses. Each column contains rows that are a response to a subset of the same question (question 10: 10_1, 10_2 etc). I am looking to see how responses compare to voting habits in the dataset with 3 voting habit choices per respondent. The individual queries work on their own and this UNION works with the caveat that it does not order the results reflecting the order of the select clauses

Comment: All of that information needs to be in the question, along with sample data and the output you want to obtain from that data. Please [edit] your question to provide the information there, where it belongs, rather than burying it in a comment. As your query is currently written, it returns exactly two columns, and it's unclear what you expect.

Comment: @KenWhite I dont know if my response was confusing but essentialy I am trying to return the voting categories of each Q10 grouped by voting category in order of the select clauses & union

Comment: It's still unclear. Please [edit] your post to provide the information there, **along with** sample data and the output you expect to obtain from that data. We can each repeat the same information in the comments for the next few days or months or years, but you're not going to get an answer until you provide that information.

Answer (score 0):

Can try something like this.  Add a column, in this case "seq", to each select and set the value to the order you're trying to achieve.  Then order by seq.

```
(SELECT seq = 1, voter_category, 
count (voter_category) as responses 
FROM `bootcamp-application-project.voters_survey.survey_responses` 
where q10_1 = 1      -- Receiving long-term disability 
                    -- 1 is Yes response
group by voter_category) 
UNION ALL
( SELECT seq = 2, voter_category, 
count (voter_category) as responses_2
FROM `bootcamp-application-project.voters_survey.survey_responses` 
where Q10_2 = 1      -- Have a chronic illness 
group by voter_category)
order by seq, voter_category
```